# Shipping methods is not working in Magento 2

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.3

[image]

**The Shipping methods** are not working in Magento 2.

I have set all configuration settings. But, Not reflecting any changes on the checkout page or cart page.

[image]

Comment: please specify what is really your problem. You can enable shipping methods from Configuration of the Shipping Methods

Comment: @magefms I also all flate rate & free shipping method all changes but not any reflact checkout page

Comment: Please include screenshot of your configuration in admin for enabled shipping methods as well as the checkout area

Comment: yes sure I am edit screenshot

Comment: I see, are you using a third party extension? or a third party theme other than Magento default? If yes, please try to use Magento default and check if issue still exists

Comment: Check in quote table whether quote has been set to virtual

Comment: check if you are able to place order without filling shipping step its mean your products are set to virtual so change it to simple it will start showing shipping method. if not then check if you see any error in console log.

Comment: yes Thanks all working only default luma theme but not working third party theme